# How to implement JWT(JsonWebToken) logout in node express

Tags: node.js, session, express, jwt, logout

I create new login web application using node express using jwt as the authentication method. But I cant expires the token as a single logout button click. Time based session expiry is possible. But how can I expires token using single logout button click.

Comment: just delete the token cookie and hard reload the page?

Comment: dynamically delete the cookie.?

Comment: cookie can delete from server side or client side, what kind of dynamic do you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

**There are some approaches to logout by jsonwebtoken in nodejs.**

1.Remove token from the client.

But this for the client side.This approach fails when someone stolen the token before logout.

2.Token expiry times get short and rotate them often.